# Get inputs from request POST to Python app file

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and I have been trying to figure this out for fews days

This is my request.py

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:5000/predict_api'
r = requests.post(url,json={'City':'Berlin', 'Country':'DE', 'Target_PtoD':36,'Start Date':"1/8/2021",'End Date':"14/8/2021"})
```

I want to store the inputs from the post to object variables like below. When I manually assign variables in the code like below, it works but when I try get it from the request. I get errors

```
city = 'Berlin'
Country='DE'
Target_PtoD=36
start='14/7/2021'
end='31/7/2021'
```

I have tried the following

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])

def predict():
city = request.values.get('City')
Country=request.values.get('Country')
Target_PtoD=request.values.get('Target_PtoD')
start=request.values.get('Start Date')
end=request.values.get('End Date')
```

But for some reason the wrong input gets stored.

Anyone familiar with this, request your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

First, you name your endpoint `predict`, but you call `predict_api` in your `request.py`.

Second, I am not sure how to use `request.values`, which returns a `CombinedMultiDict` - if you insist to use `request.values`, have a look at the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.values).

It would be easier to use `request.json`.

So you get the value for the City by `city = request.json.get('City')`.

It is straightforward to debug such problems with a debugger, such as `pdb`.

I created a 5 min lightning talk for Python Ireland:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxkco-gS4S8

Comment: Thanks for your message. Using request.data, I get the following the error----- 'bytes' object is not callable

Comment: @Datalearner I used your code and run it on my PC - so, I am not sure how it can break with your error message. Usually, it is a good idea to include the complete traceback. Anyhow, my answer has been edited by @davidism to use `request.json`. This also works - I just confirmed it on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do

```
request_json = request.get_json()
City = request_json.get("City")
Country = request_json.get("Country")
# etc...
```

using the .get_json() function first will return a dictionary of the whole json body and that is much easier to work with

Comment: I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'